# Nested Span element URL text value - Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the value #2011 which is a URL text from the HTML below. I tried the below code but didnt work. It says it is unable to locate the class

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class = "data-issue-and-pr-hovercards-enabled"]').get_attribute('a')
```

Can anyone help to correct the mistake? I am new to selenium.

```
<span data-issue-and-pr-hovercards-enabled>
  <span><span> · Fixed by <a href="https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/pull/2011" data-hydro-click="{&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;issue_cross_references.click&quot;,&quot;payload&quot;:{&quot;reference_location&quot;:&quot;ISSUE_HEADER&quot;,&quot;user_id&quot;:8344482,&quot;issue_id&quot;:490664092,&quot;pull_request_id&quot;:315249262,&quot;originating_url&quot;:&quot;https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/2008&quot;}}" data-hydro-click-hmac="aadfd36202d72a8e9a7ce379994bac18a7e2052adfb12d43eea1c8f41e12bfde" data-hovercard-type="pull_request" data-hovercard-url="/mlpack/mlpack/pull/2011/hovercard">#2011</a></span><span></span></span>
</span>
```

Here is the link to the website - github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/2008 I want to get the #2011 which is next to the Fixed by Text (below the title of the issue). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below XPath:
This relative xpath will search for all tag names(*) which contains the text "#2011"

`//*[contains(text(),'#2011')]`

Or try the below one: Very similar explanation as above but this will search only within `<a>` tag

`//a[contains(text(),'#2011')]`

**Update:**

Try the below XPath:

`//span[contains(text(),'Fixed by')]//a`

Use `.text` method to fetch the required value. This will get you the below text value.
[image]

Comment: the things is, i dont know the value of #x.. so i have to get it based on the rest of the details.

Comment: Please try the updated XPath.

Comment: The update actually works!! Thanks bro! but just I replaced the single quote with double quote. //span[contains(text(),"Fixed by")]//a

Answer (score 1):

In the given HTML *`data-issue-and-pr-hovercards-enabled`* is an attribute but not the value of class.

---

To extract the text ***#2011*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-issue-and-pr-hovercards-enabled] a[data-hovercard-type='pull_request'][data-hovercard-url='/mlpack/mlpack/pull/2011/hovercard']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-issue-and-pr-hovercards-enabled]//a[@data-hovercard-type='pull_request' and @data-hovercard-url='/mlpack/mlpack/pull/2011/hovercard']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what I am looking for. Here is the link to the website - https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/issues/2008 I want to get the #2011 which is next to the Fixed by Text (below the title of the issue). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: There are 2 similar instances of the text `#2011`, _Fixed by #2011_ and _closed this as completed in #2011_. Which one are you looking at?

Comment: Its the first one on the top.

Comment: Thanks bro. The above comment worked - //span[contains(text(),"Fixed by")]//a